# Can ResponseCache vary by only a cookie value?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, http-caching

Can a response cache vary according to a specific cookie value ?

I only see VaryByHeader option which takes an header name, so it varies by "all cookies" ?

```
[ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "Cookie")]
```

Comment: "vary according to a specific cookie value": No.  Vary only accepts a header name or a list of header names. See [vary on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Vary#Syntax) . And also see [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.4) : "The value consists of either a single asterisk ("*") or a list of header field names
   (case-insensitive)"

Comment: @itminus that's what I thought, I wonder why is this so, wouldn't be useful to vary cache based on a single cookie value ? varying by all cookies is not very useful :/

Comment: I believe it's not related to ASP.NET Core itself. It is a HTTP Caching Standard. Even if you provide an implementation for ASP.NET Core itself, what about those caching servers? Most of them are not implemented in C#. On the other hand, those caching servers might belong to ISP. Or maybe they are some enterprise internal servers , you cannot replace all the caching servers, right?

Comment: Of course, my comment was not a criticism of .net core feature, I just wonder why it has not been decided in standard that varying http caches by a single cookie value could be useful. Maybe it is a sign that I want to do something wrong, but I would like to understand what

Comment: @itminus The varyBy-attributes are used for server-side response caching. They do not affect the cache-control behavior of clients. So, the question is valid.